# Cream puff shell shaping

Tags: puff-pastry

I am trying to figure out the best way to shape my cream puff shells into a volcano shape for baking. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @Wendy! Have you made cream puffs before?

Comment: Sorry, this may be a language issue, but what are your shells made of? Pate a choux, puff pastry, something else?

Answer (score 1):

My mother used a large cake decorating sleeve for her pastries. She would squirt out a mound, and then cut the middle out after it was finished baking.